# Asymptotic notation names

Tags: real-analysis, functions, asymptotics, terminology

Here are two asymptotic symbols:  $\asymp$ and $\sim$. I know what their mathematical definitions are, namely $f(x)\asymp g(x)$ if there exist constants $A,B$ such that $Af(x)\le g(x)\le Bf(x)$, and $f(x)\sim g(x)$ if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)=1$.

What I am not sure about is what these symbols are *called*. They are both asymptotic by definition but I have no idea what their nomenclature is.

Comment: The symbol `~` is called a *tilde*

Answer (score 0):

The relation $f \sim g$ is usually called *asymptotic equivalence*; see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis)